# WPF, read data from XmlDataProvider in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, viewmodel, xmldataprovider

I want a `TreeView` with checkboxes and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithCheckBoxes.aspx).  However, in it, he creates all his content for the `TreeView` at runtime.  I have an XML file that I have accessible as an `XmlDataProvider` in my XAML:

```
<XmlDataProvider Source="XmlData/Versions.xml" XPath="//*[count(*)=0]"
                 x:Key="versionsXml" />
```

I have a view model class with `IsChecked` and `Name` properties, and I want to use this to represent nodes in my XML:

```
<Versions>
  <Version name="1.0">
    <Version name="1.0.001" />
    <Version name="1.0.002" />
  </Version>
</Versions>
```

My `TreeView` will display leaf nodes (i.e., 1.0.001 and 1.0.002) with a checkbox.  How can I populate my `TreeView` with not the `XmlDataProvider`'s content directly, but rather a `List<MyViewModel>`?  I can create a property in my `DataContext` that returns a `List<MyViewModel>`, then bind my `TreeView` to that property, but I don't know how, in a C# property getter, to read in the XML data from the `XmlDataProvider`.  When I use `TryFindResource` and cast the `object` result to `XmlDataProvider`, the `Document` and `Data` properties are null for my `versionsXml` resource (defined in `<UserControl.Resources>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/595c90f9-513d-487b-a937-4f7045705ee7), I did the following:

```
<XmlDataProvider Source="XmlData/Versions.xml" XPath="//*[count(*)=0]"
                 x:Key="versionsXml" IsInitialLoadEnabled="True"
                 IsAsynchronous="False" />
```

Then, in C# to access the `XmlDataProvider` data since the `Data` property was no longer null:

```
var versions = new List<MyViewModel>();
var dataProvider = TryFindResource("versionsXml") as XmlDataProvider;
if (null == dataProvider)
{
    return versions;
}
var nodes = dataProvider.Data as IEnumerable;
if (null == nodes)
{
    return versions;
}
foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
{
   ...
}
```